# in-app purchase for crossplatform system

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, in-app-purchase

I have to create a system in which once user purchase in-app purchase, functionality will unlocked for his/her user account and save in our database. Now it don't matter from which Apple id user has downloaded the app, once user login in the app with this account he will be able to use this feature.

Now user either can unlock this from Android or from web for his account. Is this allowed in Apple guidelines.
Same question for Android too, is this allowed by Google?